# action script 2.0

Tags: actionscript

Hi I have a small flash as below

```
public function startApp () : Void
 {
  mcWindowRoot.refToClass = this;
  mcNext = mcWindowRoot;
  _oLogoutDelegate = Delegate.create (this, onLogoutHandler);
  _oWindowManagerRef.addEventListener ("onLogout", _oLogoutDelegate);
  loadWhatNext ();
 }
 /**
 * Enter description here
 *
 */
 function loadWhatNext (mc : MovieClip) : Void
 {
  var doneFinish = mcNext.container.attachMovie ("done", "done", mcNext.container.getNextHighestDepth ());
  //var returnPage = mcNext.container.attachMovie ("item", "item", mcNext.container.getNextHighestDepth () , 
              //{
               //_x : 135, _y : 230
              //});

  var miRefTemp = _oWindowManagerRef;
  //returnPage.item_txt.htmlText = _level0.account_Return;
  //returnPage.onPress = 
  doneFinish.onPress = function ()
  {
   trace ("AccountNext returnPage.onPress doneFinish.onPress" )
   trace ("AccountNext miRefTemp " + miRefTemp)
   trace ("AccountNext this.refToClass " + this._parent._parent.refToClass)
   trace ("AccountNext this " + this)
   this._parent._parent.refToClass.closeWindow ();

   _oShell.loadWindow( "", null);
  }

  if (aNextdata != undefined && aNextdata.length > 0)
  {
   for (var i = 0 ; i < 3; i ++)
   {
    if (aNextdata [i].text != undefined)
    {
     var tempItem = mcNext.copy.attachMovie ("item", "item" + i, i, 
     {
      _x : 143, _y : 150 + (i * 20)
     });
     tempItem.item_txt.htmlText = aNextdata [i].text;
     tempItem.url = aNextdata [i].link;
     tempItem.refToClass = _refWindow;
     var asInterpreter = new asFunctionInterpreter (_oWindowManagerRef._oWindowManagerRef.oController.propertiesMap.get ("BaseURL") , this);
     var deepLinks : Object = new Object ();

     deepLinks = asInterpreter.getAsSingleURL ( aNextdata [i].link );

     tempItem.deepLinks = deepLinks;

     trace("Next :: LINKS : " + tempItem.wModule );

     tempItem.oShell = _oShell;
     tempItem.onPress = function ()
     {
      if (this.deepLinks.type == "internal")
      {
       this.oShell.loadWindow( this.deepLinks.wModule , this.deepLinks.wParams);
      } 
      else
      {
       getURL (this.deepLinks.link, "_blank");
      }

      this.refToClass.closeWindow ();
     }
    }
   }
  } else
  {
   trace ("end tab " + _refWindow);
  }
 }
 /**
 * Enter description here
 *
 * @param  evt
 */
 private function onLogoutHandler (evt : Object) : Void
 {
  _oWindowManagerRef.removeEventListener ("onLogout", _oLogoutDelegate);
  closeWindow ();
 }
 /**
 * Enter description here
 *
 */
 public function closeMyWindow () : Void
 {
  _global._doNav ('windowType:wclose')
 }
 /**
 * Enter description here
 *
 */
 public function removeMyWindow () : Void
 {
  _oWindowManagerRef.removeWindow (idWindow);
 }
}
```

If you can see from this part of the code

```
if (aNextdata != undefined && aNextdata.length > 0)
```

I am getting three links one below the other but my problem is only the first link is opening in a new page which is supposed to open in the same page so what should I do for this Please help me thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from your question, but it could be the getUrl-call that is causing your link to open in a new window. The second, optional, parameter to getUrl specifies the window in which the link should open. If you replace

```
getURL (this.deepLinks.link, "_blank");
```

with

```
getURL (this.deepLinks.link);
```

Your link should open in the same window.